Croatian characters in SQL for Informix database, using R
When I use a command such as the following:
DBI::dbGetQuery(my_connection,
    "SELECT * from my_table WHERE prezime IN ('Kovač', 'Šokač')")

I get the following error:
[Informix][Informix ODBC Driver][Informix]An illegal character has been found in the statement.  
[Informix][Informix ODBC Driver][Informix]A syntax error has occurred. 

If I use the same command, but formulate the query without Croatian characters: IN ('Kovac', 'Sokac') I successfuly get a resulting dataframe. However, the results obviously aren't the same since they are filtered by different words.
How can I fix this? The connection should be using the croatian locale for the database. Perhaps I'm formulating the connection string wrong? It looks like this:
my_connection <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), .connection_string = "Dsn=my_db;Driver=Informix;NODEFDAC=yes;UID=user;PWD=xxxx;CLIENT_LOCALE=hr_HR.utf8;DB_LOCALE=hr_HR.utf8;")

What is the LOCALE of the Informix database?

my DBA confirmed the locale is hr_HR.utf8
